# AIR Android runtime memory leak

Tags: android, actionscript-3, memory-leaks, air, runtime

Good day,

I am developing an adventure game in AIR for Android. I am instantiating levels from the library (movie clips), each containing at least one HD resolution bitmap.

When the game starts, it occupies about 150MB of memory, including the AIR runtime and the SWF. Out of this 150MB the SWF is about 12MB at this time.

As the game progresses the memory consumption of the AIR runtime increases, while the memory used by the SWF remains at around 15-20MB. When the total memory consumption reaches about 350(!)MB, the OS intervenes and kills the app.

I was careful to reuse objects whenever I could, and nullify any unused objects to make them eligible for GC. GC seems to be working as it should, as the memory used by the SWF remains steady around 15-20MB. I can see it drop from 20 to 12 from time to time when GC kicks in.

Things I've tried:

- Removed all cacheAsBitmap and cacheAsBitmapMatrix properties.
- Exported each level into a separate SWF and loaded them from there instead of the library.
- Forced the GC hack just to see if it has any effect.
- Fiddled with System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent(n) with different values for n.
- Tried different acceleration modes (direct and auto) thinking maybe the GPU is at fault.

All failed, memory consumption just runs away.

This happens only on Android. On a PC everything is fine, the whole thing takes up about 250-300MB, and this number remains steady, no matter how many levels I load one after another. Didn't have the chance to test on iOS yet.

I would really appreciate any ideas or insights into how to make this problem go away.

Thanks.

Comment: That you set a variable to null does not mean that it will be collected by the GC right away. If you are using large bitmaps, you should use the dispose() method of the bitmapdata class to release the memory right away.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the dispose() method. Problem is that these bitmaps were placed manually on the timeline in the Flash IDE. Each level is a complex MovieClip containing bitmaps and other MCs on the timeline. At runtime these bitmaps are internally converted to shapes and their BitmapData becomes inaccessible. I'll look into placing these bitmaps on the displaylist via script so I can destroy them when they are not needed. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Easiest way to find memory leak is to use Adobe Flash Builder. Just run profiling.

2) Also good way to exclude leaks in future: create function which will be used for "cleaning". E.g. it will null all local variables of instance and so on. Something like usual c++ destructors. Then, before nulling your object, just call this method.

Comment: I only used the Flash IDE until now, I'm not familiar with Flash Builder. Nevertheless, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that it colud connect as profiler to any swf which compiled with debug mode on :)